# Вывод строк в файл на си

Tags: c, файлы

Необходимо перенести строки из одного файла в другой, причем в каждой строке есть три слова и два пробела между ними. Предоставляю код:

```
int  kstr, i;
int A[36];
FILE* obj;
FILE* out;

if (((obj = fopen("objects.txt", "r")) != NULL &&
     (out = fopen("output.txt", "w")) != NULL)
{
    fscanf(obj, "%d\n",&kstr); // определяем количество строк(задано в файле)`введите сюда код`

    for (i = 0; i < kstr; i++)
    {
        fscanf(obj, "%s\n", &A[i]);
        fprintf(out, "%s\n", A[i]);
    }

    fclose(obj);
    fclose(out);
}
else
{
    printf("not files");
    exit(1);
}
```

Сборка программы заканчивается ошибкой, что исправить для корректной работы? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вам нужно скопировать файл?

Comment: Не совсем, в файле objects есть строки: в первой строке число= количеству остальных строк, а в последующих строках три числа в каждой, разделенных двумя пробелами. необходимо эти строки с тремя числами записать в файл output

Comment: **Сборка программы заканчивается ошибкой** - какой ошибкой? Приведите текст сообщения об ошибке.

Для начала - Вы пытаетесь переменную A[i]  целого типа прочитать по формату %s. И вывести в выходной файл...  Это плохая идея. Надо использовать формат %d.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, первое: куда вы пытаетесь записать строку? В массив int? Второе: scanf со спецификатором %s читает только одно слово, а не целую строку. В вашем случае лучше воспользоваться либо fgets и fputs (если нужно перенести строго определенное количество строк), либо следующим кодом:

```
while ((ch = getc (obj)) != EOF)
    putc (ch, out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, вам нужно просто выбросить первую строку и переписать все остальные строки в неизменном виде.

После открытия файлов:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE]; // BUFSIZE выберите сами
fgets(buf,BUFSIZE,obj);
while(fgets(buf,BUFSIZE,obj))
    fputs(buf,out);
```

Если ну позарез хочется с числами, как у вас, и у вас именно числа, а не слова, и именно по три:

```
    fscanf(obj, "%d\n", &kstr);
    for (i = 0; i < kstr; i++)
    {
        int a,b,c;
        fscanf(obj, "%d %d %d", &a,&b,&c);
        fprintf(out, "%d %d %d\n", a,b,c);
    }
```

И, кстати, у вас в выражении условия `if` количество скобок `(` больше количества скобок `)` - какая уж тут компиляция :) (о спецификаторе `%s` вам уже писали).